# Ruby: CSV instead of database

Tags: ruby, csv

Is there a framework or gem or similar to use a CSV as a database? Like if I wanted to quickly run a few Ruby commands on a CSV is there something I can use to load it into the console and work directly on it then re-export as CSV all without an actual database?

I know it'd be slow, etc, but it's not meant to run an app or anything, just run conversions on datasets, etc.

I guess it could be loaded into memory as a huge hash then managed like that? Something along those lines? Or is there something better?

Comment: Load CSV to the database...

Comment: Does it need to be a CSV? Object implements a `to_yaml` method which you can subsequently dump/load from file.

Comment: You're looking for Ruby's [CSV](http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib/libdoc/csv/rdoc/CSV.html) library.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No other framework needed but the CSV framework with some homebrew additions.
Something like this, for use from the command line you would just need to pass the parameters.

```
class Csv_db < CSV
  attr_accessor :rows

  def initialize file
    @rows = CSV.read file
  end

  def list
    @rows.each do |row|
        p row
    end
  end

  def add row
    @rows << row
  end

  def get rowindex
    @rows[rowindex]
  end

  def save
    ...
  end
end

csv = Csv_db.new('original.csv')
csv.list
csv.add ['field1','field2']
csv.list
p csv.get 2
```

Comment: Ah, that's super cool. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Something like

```
require 'csv'

c = CSV.open(ARGV[0], col_sep: ';', headers: true)

c.each do |row|
  row.fields.each_with_index do |value, i|
    values[c.headers[i]] ||= []
    values[c.headers[i]] << value
  end
end
```

You may also want to transform them to a struct so you can work on it easier.

```
require 'ostruct'

[...]

values.each do |k,v|
  v.each_with_index do |val, i|
    items[i] ||= OpenStruct.new
    items[i].send("#{k}=", val)
  end
end
```

to save you can do something like

```
CSV.open('file.csv', 'w', :quote_char => '"', :force_quotes => true, :encoding => "UTF-8") do |csv|
  csv << ['header1','header2']
  csv << ['row1 el1', 'row2 el2']
end
```

hope this helps